# Trying to get selenium to work property with drop down menu (select element)

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath, browser-automation

I am trying to get selenium to select a specific value from a dropdown menu.

**Here is a picture of the elements.** 
[image]

**Heres is a code of the element.**

```html
<select _ngcontent-c31="" class="input productEntry ng-valid ng-touched ng-dirty" formcontrolname="handlingUnit" tabindex="1022" style="">
    <option _ngcontent-c31="" value="0">N/A</option>
    <!---->
    <option _ngcontent-c31="" value="1" class="ng-star-inserted">Pallet</option>
    <option _ngcontent-c31="" value="2" class="ng-star-inserted">Skid</option>
    <option _ngcontent-c31="" value="3" class="ng-star-inserted">Loose</option>
    <option _ngcontent-c31="" value="4" class="ng-star-inserted">Other</option>
    <option _ngcontent-c31="" value="5" class="ng-star-inserted">Gaylord</option>
    <option _ngcontent-c31="" value="6" class="ng-star-inserted">Master Bundles</option>
    <option _ngcontent-c31="" value="7" class="ng-star-inserted">Carrier</option>
</select>
```

**Here is a picture of the website in which I am try to get selenium to auto-select. It is for the category "Handling Unit". I want it to select pallet. (First option is N/A, Second option is Pallet, Third option is Skid etc)**

[image: Interface]

I've tried the following code.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

select_element = Select(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//select[@class='input productEntry ng-valid ng-dirty ng-touched']"))
select_element.select_by_value('$1')
```

This line cause the rest of my code to bug out. What is the best way to code a select element with selenium?

**Updated Solution**

```
select_element = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html[1]/body[1]/app-root[1]/div[1]/div[1]/app-record[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/app-record-quoting[1]/div[1]/app-record-product-list-panel[1]/form[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/select[1]'))
select_element.select_by_value('1')
```

Comment: Can you please post the full code of the drop-down instead of a screenshot?

Comment: I added the code for the drop down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use Select method like this:

```
select_element = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath(''))
select_element.select_by_value('$1')
```

Also you can Use `full Xpath` instead of `Xpath` to get element with `selenium`.
In your picture, you must get `abs Xpath`. it's same as full Xpath that i said.

To get the element with selenium you can use this:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('')
```

If you want to click on it, use this:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('').click()
```

If you want to get element text, use this:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('').text
```

If you want to write a text in element, use this:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('').send_keys('')
```

You can use both abs and rell Xpath, but the problem in abs Xpath is that any changes in html can make that selenium don't find the element or find wrong element.

Comment: I added those lines of code and changes some minor changes to the parameters, the script performs the proper functionality!